# Android Studio Debugger Menu Items Greyed Out

Tags: android, debugging

I am trying to debug an application in Android Studio. The application does pick up the virtual device[my kindle] and shows what application is available for debugging . The problem is the menu items on my debugger are greyed out. I have disabled and enabled the ADB integration but to no avail. Restarting my application does not help. I have checked online for possible solutions but I am unable to solve this challenge. Setting debuggable to true in the AndroidManifest.xml does not work either.

[image: Application available for debugging]
[image: Greyed out debug menu items]

Answer (score -1):

Your adb log is saying that your connection is not authorized? When you first plug the device in, there should have been a dialog on the device asking you to trust the debug connection. This is to prevent other people from accessing your device through adb.

Comment: No this is not the problem. I get the notification that as for the trust between the PC and my device as well as the force close notification. The logs shows this " 
Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse
Waiting for process: com.example.elmundo.justjava
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'"  I have no other application that use the debugger opened

Comment: It gives me a list of devices attached:  an alpha numeric value.

Comment: What happen when you do: Run - Attach debugger to android process